# Solid State Relay Either Stuck on or not Running

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, prototyping

So I've wired up a relatively simple circuit where an Arduino controls a solid state relay that is connected to a 12V 30A power supply which runs a solenoid valve. I'm using the an Arduino [Mega 2560](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560) a [Gem Sensors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009NAQKZM) solenoid valve and a [Broadcom Limited ASSR-1511-001E](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/broadcom-limited/ASSR-1511-001E/516-2191-5-ND/2211246) solid state relay.

On the input side I have:

```
Arduino 5V --> SSR Pin 1 --> Out SSR Pin 2 --> 500 ohm resistor --> Arduino ground
```

And then on the load side I have:

```
Power supply positive terminal --> SSR Pin 6 (labeled as the positive pin) --> Out SSR Pin 5 --> Solenoid Valve --> Power supply negative terminal
```

So with that all in mind I find that when I power it all on it doesn't do anything. I've checked the voltage going through the input side and it is 5V on the dot but nothing on the load side. When I switch the connections on the load side it turns on and always stays on even with power turned off on the Arduino side and then my load side looks like:

```
Power supply negative terminal --> Solenoid Valve --> SSR Pin 6 (labeled as the positive pin) --> Out SSR Pin 5 --> Power supply negative terminal
```

Do you have any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly and what I can check to get this circuit running properly? I've got it prototyped on a perf board but it is pretty easy to switch everything around.

For some additional info:

- The SSR input side has a max suggested amperage of 20mA. I have the 500ohm resistor on that line so at 5V (subtract the 1.65 voltage drop) that is 6.7mA on that line.
- The SSR load side has a max of 2A and my solenoid valve has 20ohms of resistance so at 12V we're running around 0.5A.

Comment: How about drawing that as a schematic..... but it think your plus side on the output of the relay should be pin 6 and the negative side should be pin 4

Comment: Can you turn on your input side and measure (a) voltage across the 500 R resistor and (b) voltage across pin1-pin2 (IRLED) and post them.

Comment: @TonyM voltage across the resistor a.) is 3.5V and then voltage across the pin1-pin2 b.) is actually 0.0. So I assume that is the issue.. could I have fried the SSR? How could it have 0V across it?

Comment: @Trevor putting the negative side out on pin 5 instead of 4 is a slightly more robust circuit capable of 2A instead of 1A. I may be missing something but is there a reason I should have it on pin 4?

Comment: @Trevor, I think you've got a little muddled there, pal: pins 4/6 are for an AC load, DC load uses pin6(+) and pin 5(-), as per datasheet. OP, seen your voltages - suggest look for a short (solder whisker?) on the board, maybe solder-sucker and resolder the joints otherwise try a new part.

Comment: Ya I realise that, I was just going by their spec sheet.

Comment: 3.5 across the resistor sounds about right.... but zero across the SSR isn't are you sure the other pin is grounded. Where did the other 1.5 go?

Comment: @Trevor which other pin should be grounded? I have my ground going directly into the Arduino ground. The SSR specs say it has a 1.65V voltage drop so I assumed that wasn't a problem, should I still have 5V across the resistor?

Comment: OK correct me if I am wrong. You have 5V out, 3.5V across the resistor, yet ZERO across the LED.  That doesn't add up. What are you missing?

Comment: Issue with pin5 is we have no idea what "Turn-O-Circuit" does... but it looks like it depends on pin 5. However, with 0V across 1 & 2 it's a mute point at the moment.

Comment: Well I grabbed another multimeter with finer probes just to make sure it wasn't an incorrect reading and all the exact same. I'm going to try another one of the same SSRs just to rule that out.

Comment: Find waldo... (The missing 1.5V). Something is not wired the way you think it is.

Comment: Okay so I wired it up with an entirely new SSR, new wires, on a different breadboard. The first time I plugged it in it worked as expected. With the input voltage off it didn't power the solenoid valve. Upon sending 5V across the input side it correctly powered the solenoid load and it fired. But now, after the initial time, no matter what, the load side circuit is completed and the solenoid is always on. With or without input voltage, even after power cycling the power supply, and arduino, and waiting ~10 seconds.

Comment: #Trevor that 1.5 voltage is documented in the SSR specs as a 1.65 voltage drop, isn't that what I'm seeing?

Comment: u mentioned way up there the voltage across 1, and 2 was 0V/.. sigh. Anyways.. tell me you have an appropriate fly-back diode across that valve coil.

Comment: @Trevor that SSR is rated to 60V, do you think it really needs the flyback? I guess I should give that a shot.

Comment: @clifgray, see if you had added a schematic this whole question would have been a snap. YES you need a flyback across the coil of the solenoid. Otherwise the SSR fet will fry on the first turn off.

Comment: @clifgray and I mean the valve, not the SSr

Comment: clifgray, the tragedy, the heartbreaking tragedy, here is that you should have presented a schematic and @Trevor and myself went with you not doing so...and it backfired on us. That's a day wasted. You've no idea how many of the regular (critics...sorry...users) users here would have beaten down on you and refused to talk until you had a schematic up. And how right they are (sigh)

Comment: Well that solved it and it is working correctly now. I'm just getting started in this area so I appreciate the now totally understood requirement for a schematic. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 1):

To make the solution clear in case anyone has this same issue, I was getting some kickback from the inductive load of the solenoid valve. I had been successfully running some 2W solenoid valves with this same solid state relay without issue but then with the larger Gem Sensors 6W valves it turned out that the inductive load was frying the SSR when I turned it off. I'm now running a [1N5819 Diode](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N5817-D.PDF) as a flyback diode to protect from that inductive kickback and the circuit is running just fine. I've included a schematic below, this is my first schematic so let me know if anything is unclear!

[image]

Comment: You drew the SSR backwards,,, but as I suspected, you needed a fly-back diode.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a SSR is for AC only, not dc. Because DC never crosses 0 volts, the SCR can never turn off once energized.

A better DC switch would be a transistor or FET.

Comment: I was thinking that might be an issue but this one has in the documentation: "ASSR-1511 enables AC/DC and DC-only output connections. For DC-only connection, the output current, Io, increases to 2A and the on-resistance, R(ON) reduces to 0.2ohm."

Comment: DC SSRs are made from FETs, AC SSRs use triacs. It's pretty poor to not even look at the datasheet before writing an answer, which clearly shows all this.